# randomize numbers without any std- function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I need help to random numbers without any std-function. How can I do that? I know that I can do it with the random-function like:

```
v2 = rand() % 36 + 1;
```

which will randomize numbers between 1-35, but the `rand()` function belongs to the " (stdlib.h)" std.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you cannot use the standard library? It looks like an extremely arbitrary (and stupid) limitation.

Comment: Look for pseudo random number generators on the internet and implement one.

Comment: That produces integers between 1 and **36**.

Comment: @Angew: most likely a school assignment.

Comment: `int random() { return 7; }`

Comment: its an school assignment therefore I cannot use the std?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar question on stackoverflow : [How do I generate random numbers without rand() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602919/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-without-rand-function)

I make little modifications for generating between 0-35 and final solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 36;
    time_t sec;
    sec=time(NULL);
        for(;;)
        {
            sec=sec%3600;
            if(num>=sec)
            {
            printf("%ld\n",sec);
            break;
            }
            sec=sec%num;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Here we are using `<time.h>`for `time` instead of `<stdlib.h>` for `rand()`
if we don't want 0 as answer then we can add

```
while(sec==0)
{
    sec=time(NULL); 
}
```

before this statement : `sec=sec%3600;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use hardware random number generator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "immintrin.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned int val;
    _rdrand32_step(&val);
    std::cout << val;
}
```