# c/c++ - random number between 0 and 1 without using rand()

Tags: c++, c, random

I am trying to generate a (pseudo) random number between 0 and 1 without using any functions like rand() or srand().
I found some answers here but none fit my problem.

I was thinking about something like

- declaring a variable and getting a pointer to that variable
- add a number to the pointer to get another pointer to a unknown memory address (I know it is bad practise)
- doing some modulo operations and some bit shifting on the new variable
  I would like it to be as distributed as possible

thanks!

Comment: Have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7602919/5994074

Comment: Unpredictable is not the same as random.