# How can we create random numbers without using any function rand in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
b=round(rand(1,20));
```

Instead of using the function `rand`, I would like to know how to create such series.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: Do you want to get zeros and ones as in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. Actually, the easiest way to go, in my opinion is to use a [Linear-feedback Shift Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). You can find plenty of examples and implementations googling around ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602919/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-without-rand-function) is one coming from another SO question).

Here is a quick Matlab demo based on [this code](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22716-kasami-sequences--m-sequences--linear-feedback-shift-registers?focused=5126220&tab=function):

```
b = lfsr(20)

function r = lfsr(size)
    persistent state;

    if (isempty(state))
        state = uint32(1);
    end

    if (nargin < 1)
        size = 1;
    end

    r = zeros(size,1);

    for i = 1:size
        r(i) = bitand(state,uint32(1));

        if (bitand(state,uint32(1)))
            state = bitxor(bitshift(state,-1),uint32(142));
        else
            state = bitshift(state,-1);
        end
    end
end
```