# How to generate random number between two numbers in C? (Kernel)

Tags: c, random, operating-system, kernel

I want to generate random number between two numbers in C (Kernel). It's easy in C with standard library, but in C without library, I just found this links: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768180/rand-implementation), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602919/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-without-rand-function) and I don't know how can I use the codes are in links.

I cannot show my code. Because my code is too long (+1000 lines of code).

**Edit**

Here is my incomplete code:

```
#include <lib.h>

int rand()
{
    unsigned long int next = 1;
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next / 65536) % (RAND_MAX + 1);
}

int rrand(int min, int max)
{
    /* incomplete */
}
```

lib.h:

```
#ifndef _LIB_H
# define _LIB_H
#endif

#ifdef _LIB_H
# ifndef _DEF_H /* this line isn't important for this question */
#  include <def.h> /* this line isn't important for this question */
# endif

# define RAND_MAX 32767
extern int rand();
extern int rrand(int min, int max);
extern void *malloc(size_t size); /* this line isn't important for this question */
extern int atoi(char *str); /* this line isn't important for this question */
extern char *itoa(int value, char *str, int base); /* this line isn't important for this question */
#endif
```

**Edit 2**

I can compile my code without error.

Comment: What's wrong with the questions/answers in the links?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I cannot generate random number using answers in questions. I don't know how can I generate random number e.g. between 5 and 25 using answers in questions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Is there any problem in my question that needs to be edited?

Comment: So why are you unable to use the code proposed in the links? What did you try? Are you unable to compile the code? Does it run but the results you get are not the results you expect? Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: If you're using 1000+ lines of code for a function that generates pseudo random numbers and a function that selects from a range you're overdoing it.

Comment: Suggestion: do not use Standard identifiers (`RAND_MAX`, `rand`, `malloc`, `atoi`) in your code unless you're writing a Standard library.

Comment: @pmg No, my kernel can: 1. Clear screen if input is `clr`, 2. Change cursor shape if input is `cursorset cursorcode`, 3. Print on screen if input is `echo "String`, 4. reboot if input is `reboot`, 5. shutdown if input is `shutdown`, 6. Open console calculator if input is `calc`. I need to generate random number between two numbers for my calculator.

Comment: @pmg I not making standard library, but I making a library for my kernel. Do you want me place my code at GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do a function to generate a random number up to, and excluding, `n`

```
unsigned randto(unsigned n) {
    unsigned r, hi = (RAND_MAX / n) * n; // avoid
    do r = rand(); while (r >= hi);      // bias
    return r % n;
}
```

With this function (and, of course, `rand()`), you can easily write your `rrand()`

```
unsigned rrand(unsigned lo, unsigned hi) {
    return lo + randto(hi - lo + 1);
}
```

Comment: Where is assert() function?

Comment: assert not needed, removed... but don't go calling `rrand(100, 10);`

Comment: error: ‘hi’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: copy/paste error :-) https://ideone.com/XMs2st

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one line.

Comment: I compiled it without error, but it seems like rrand() only generates one number.

Comment: The error you're experiencing is in your version of `rand()`: try it: `for (unsigned k = 0; k < 100; k++) { printf("%d ", rand()); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232272/discussion-between-ariankg-and-pmg).

Comment: Please check discussion.

Comment: copy/paste error surely. The last version with `static` I posted on ideone works flawlessly.

Comment: I think you didn't get it. For example, if I use `rrand(first_input, second_input)`, in first output (First input: 1, Second input: 10), I can see [2, 3, 7]. But after a reboot, second output (First input: 1, Second input: 10) is [2, 3, 7] again. Note that it was just an example.

Comment: Ah... `static unsigned long int next = 1; // <============== static keyword` is to blame. You want to initialize (*seed*) the random number generator with a different value everytime. Most people use `time(0)` to initialize with number of seconds since Unix epoch; maybe you can use the same or use a counter outside your program (in a  file) or some other way to keep seeding the `next` without recompiling.

Comment: `time(0)`? I have no standard library in my kernel. How can I use `time()`?

Comment: "Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." -- John von Neumann (1951) from [wikipedia article on PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)